# Excel connector with ODATA filter work not as expected

Tags: excel, filter, odata, azure-logic-apps

Sorry,  I see there are some posts with ODATA filter but i found nothing here about logical Apps excel connector with  an ODATA filter problem.

I have such a simple table for-Mail Adresses and in in the Logic App.  I used a Excel(Business) - Connector with List rows present in a table.
For reducing the amount of repsonse data, i tried to use a ODATA filter.

```
(endswith(Email,'@xx.de'))
```

and

```
(Email ne '')
```

but it didnt worked.
Only after the first gap (empty cell) search will continue, further gaps will end the search.
Because there are only singel filter supported I don't know a solution for that.
Can anyone help me?

| Expected Response | real Response |
| --- | --- |
| 444444444444@xx.de | 444444444444@xx.de |
| 444444444444@000.com | 444444444444@000.com |
| 122gfgf@xx.de |  |
| 12256565656gfgf@xx.de |  |
| 33334444444@000.com |  |
| 123gfgf@xx.de |  |
| 0000gfgf@xx.de |  |

| Expected Response | real Response |
| --- | --- |
| 122gfgf@xx.de |  |

*the above 2 tables should be 1 table, but markdown shows me an error if I added the last row as extra table.*

*Here is my table:*

| E-Mail |
| --- |
| 222222222222@xx.de |
| 333333333333@xx.de |
|  |
| 5444444444444@xx.de |
| 444444444444@xx.de |
|  |
| 444444444444@000.com |
| 122gfgf@xx.de |
| 12256565656gfgf@xx.de |
| 33334444444@000.com |
| 123gfgf@xx.de |
|  |
| 0000gfgf@xx.de |
|  |
|  |
|  |
|  |
| 124gfgf@xx.de |

Comment: if someone could tell me how i had aproblem an creating the 1st table (last row everytine produces an error) on posting this topic i was appreciated too.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use one filter:

```
endswith(Email,'@xx.de')
```

Do not need `Email ne ''` because the empty cell can also be filtered by `endswith(Email,'@xx.de')`.

============================**Update**=============================

My creating excel steps:

**1.** new excel

[image]

**2.** open the excel and insert the table

[image]

Comment: endswith(Email,'@xx.de') was only an example.  I need all not empty  entries.
I cannpot ensure correct table size & gaps through deletion.
The gaps are my problem the ODATA filter I tried.  Both filter worked but endwdth is not usefull  because only 1 filtercondition is allowed and with more than 1 gap there are mssing entries, I need a filter condition that doesn't stop after 1st gap if possible .

See my real response and i would reach  the expected response. So you was very hhelpfull in other topics , thank you for that.  But i need the Expected Response of different endings.

Comment: Hi @ingo_ww I'm a little confused. You mentioned you want all not empty entries, so isn't using `Email ne ''` enough ? And I also confused about your description of `more than 1 gap there are missing entries` because I test with `Email ne ''` and it works fine. It doesn't stop at 1st empty cell.

Comment: Hi @HuryShen now I am really confused, because on my cases it was reproducable many many time times yesterday. Can you describe the steps creating the excel file. I forgot something used released dokuments sharepoint group instead! Could this have effect? And  My example Table is not complete there are 58 valid email adresses at start.  I could remove at weekend these entries and try it again.
But now I am really confused.

Comment: Hi @ingo_ww I have updated the answer with my creating excel steps.

Comment: I have an idea why you have not the problem, i go the limits of excel.
So for preparing excel for user which not very affinate with it topics, i the problem with extend the table, if not adapted the table range on every change, the coneector misses cells.
To avoid this i tested 2048 or 10000 linesbut insert the tabel  as max range (i think near 1 million ) and i set the pagination of th excel connector to 10.000 and then I would use the ODATA filter. I think the paggination and the max table range makes a difference.
If I have time i correct my question.